# Java SE: @Inject does not work in Bean Validation validators called by RESTEasy

Tags: cdi, resteasy, hibernate-validator

The following code from [Hibernate Validator Reference Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.3/reference/en-US/html_single/#example-constraint-validator-injected-bean) does not work in Java SE when RESTEasy is calling the validation:

```
public class ValidLicensePlateValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidLicensePlate, String> {

    @Inject
    private VehicleRegistry vehicleRegistry;

    //rest of the class
```

The field `vehicleRegistry` is **never injected**.

Note that I have `hibernate-validator-cdi.jar` on the classpath.

Any idea what could be wrong with my setup? Or is this a bug in RESTEasy?

---

Here are (possibly misleading) outcomes of my investigation:

1. During application start RESTEasy shows the info log:

   ```
   RESTEASY008550: Unable to find CDI supporting ValidatorFactory. Using default ValidatorFactory
   ```
2. From RESTEasy source code it seems that CDI enabled ValidationFactory is being looked up in [`AbstractValidatorContextResolver`](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/providers/resteasy-validator-provider-11/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/validation/AbstractValidatorContextResolver.java) calling `context.lookup("java:comp/ValidatorFactory")` but it fails and non-CDI enabled ValidationFactory is used instead.

Comment: Do you have a CDI implementation on your classpath?

Comment: Yes, @Inject works OK in REST resources and all other classes

Comment: From looking at RESTEasy's [source code](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/providers/resteasy-validator-provider-11/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/validation/AbstractValidatorContextResolver.java#L39..L66), it seems the validator factory will only be CDI-enabled if it can be obtained via JNDI (which it can in a full Java EE container). So you may try and get the validator factory via Hibernate Validator's CDI portable extension and register it in JNDI yourself (there are some stand-alone impls). Probably also worth opening a feature request in RESTEasy's issue tracker.